# What is this android.permission.STATUS_BAR_SERVICE used for? And what is the difference between uses-permission and permission?

Tags: android, android-manifest, user-permissions, android-permissions, android-sdk-tools

I want to know more about this permission and its signature level?

```
<permission
        android:name="android.permission.STATUS_BAR_SERVICE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

Like why and what is it used for ?
Is this permission used for allowing some special feature?

Also i want to know the difference between   `<permission>` and   `<uses-permission>`

I am using a `foreground service` and `NotificationManager` and i am making an app that has skype like behaviour so i want to know whether this permission has any use for me or not.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `STATUS_BAR_SERVICE` permission is used for apps that what to be the actual status bar. This is a protected permission so unless you're building your own ROM that includes replacing the status bar then I don't think this is the permission you want.

By the sound of it all you want to do is put notifications in the notification bar. So just using the functionality [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) should be all your interested in. You shouldn't need to mess with any special status bar related permissions.

Comment: Can I use Xposed to acquire this permission and use this service for a 3rd-party app?